# Overriding core blocks with backend logic for specific theme

Tags: blocks, magento-2.0

Im having trouble of understading not the override itself but how to override from theme with backend logic. so here is my question do i have to override Blocks in `app/code` or can do it from `app/design` . I am asking this because i would like to have this overrides only for one theme.

For example i would like to show Working hours in footer (only for one theme) do i have to make a module and enable it or can i do it in theme itself so when the user picks that theme it gets overriden and shown in Footer Block? Or did i understood this wrong.

**EDIT** I have done it from the module as i need some backend logic. As i didnt know if that could be done from theme itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite files in `app/design`.

You have two options, to [extend the existing XML](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-extend.html) which I would advise if you just need to add your own template. Or you can ignore existing XML and create you're own which is the [overriding the XML](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html).

---

*I am presuming you just need to add a template and there is no backend logic required so a module is unnecessary. If this is not correct then ignore the rest as you will be better off keeping the template inside the module (`app/code`) so it remains with the rest of the module.*

In your example I think it would be best to extend the existing XML and add a template. So if you wanted your template to display in the footer on every page you would do the following:

1. Create layout:

   ```
   app/design/frontend/PartyShowroom/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
   ```
2. Add your block, example:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
           <referenceContainer name="footer">
               <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="working.hours" after="footer.payments" template="Magento_Theme::html/footer/working-hours.phtml" />
           </referenceContainer>
       </body>
   </page>
   ```
3. Add your template:

   ```
   app/design/frontend/**VENDOR**/**THEME**/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer/working-hours.phtml
   ```
4. Add your working hours to that template.

You could also do this with a static block, to do this use the below XML instead:

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_name">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">static_block_name_here</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but as you said i have to add some backend logic i guess i didnt explain very good my bad (will edit question so it will be easier to understand). I guess i will have to do it from module then, As i tought it would be possible to add logic form the theme itself since i didnt found answer about that anywhere so i asked here.

Comment: Ahh I see, yeah if you have created a module for the working hours then it makes sense to keep the template within the module. Then if you need to extend it it a later date you can do so in the theme, for example if your store goes international and you create a Spanish store that needs some changes to the template.

Comment: Thank you for the hint really helped a lot as i will use a different language and almost forgot about extendending it from module. I would give you +100 if i could. Have a nice day

Comment: No problems it's what we're all here for, you to!